# Synthesize ivar declaration without overriding parent getter/setters

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, inheritance, getter-setter

I have two basic classes that inherits each other:

**BaseClass:**

```
// .h
@interface BaseClass : NSObject
@property int myProperty;
@end

// .m
@synthesize myProperty = _myProperty;
```

**ChildClass:**

```
// .h
@interface Child : BaseClass
@end
```

In `ChildClass.m`, I want to access `BaseClass` `myProperty`'s getter/setter using the `_myProperty` ivar:

```
// ChildClass.m
_myProperty = 1;
```

Of course, the parent's `@synthesize` isn't visible from `ChildClass`, so I can't just use `_myProperty`.

If I put `@synthesize myProperty = _myProperty` in `ChildClass.m`, the parent's getter/setter are overridden, and that's not what I want.

Is there a way to make an alias without overriding parent's methods ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare it manually.  Then, you can have complete control over the scope access of the iVars.

`@protected` gives subclass access, and `@package` makes it visible to everything in the implementation image (not really useful in iOS where you can't implement your own shared framework images).

For more details:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use the ivar name `_myProperty` but you can (and should) use the superclass's accessor methods:

```
prop = self.myProperty;
[self setMyProperty:newVal];  //or self.myProperty = newVal if you prefer
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I don't want to do. If you think I can't access `myProperty` through `_myProperty` (with a kind of alias), then this question might not have an answer. This is sad.

Comment: You can make a variable public, but it's virtually never done, and usually considered poor design.  Out of curiosity, why can't you use the accessors?  That's what they're there for.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, but you have to make the backing ivar visible:

```
@interface MyTest : NSObject
{
@public
    int _foo;
}
@property int foo;

@end
@interface MyTestSuper : MyTest
@end
```

then to do it:

```
MyTestSuper *x = [MyTestSuper new];
x->_foo = 5;
```

PS: this works if you just use "foo" as the backing ivar.